# WCF - Two way communciation? Not Peer-to-peer

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wcf, client-server

I have developed a WCF Self Hosted Service, which offers a contract and so on and so forth. This has been working really well, and clients call methods of the service, and receive their replies. Great.

Now, I am "playing around" with the idea for a new app, and I am curious as to how WCF, in a client server setup as above, would communicate both ways, without being called by the client.

I.e., the service contacting the client, and not the client contacting the service.

I would guess that you would somehow keep the clients "connected" and keep track of them. I worked on this scenario a while ago using raw tcp, and rolling my own routines to do this. I would now like to re-do this using WCF.

Bunch of connected clients ->>> Server.

- Clients can access methods on server, get their returns.
- Server can issue commands to clients, without being asked for something by the client.

I don't want to go peer-to-peer route, as I don't need the client connected to each other, and I wish to get past NAT restrictions on the client side. They should initiate the connection, and then "stay" connected, receiving work at times.

Taking what I know about WCF, and my previous implementation of it, its stateless, and the client does all the "calling".

Any pointers or links I can study?. All the "client/server" wcf examples I can find, are just a normal one way implementation, like I have done previously. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: When I have made two way connections with WCF I have used [duplex services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You might want to read if it can do what you want.

Comment: Hi @Jermay, add your comment as an answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I have made two way connections with WCF I have used [duplex services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You might want to read if it can do what you want.